# Mule: Inserting 470.000 records into Salesforce, that only allows 200 records per iteration

Tags: database, salesforce, mule

I hava a flow in mule that gets all records from a db around 470.000 records.
These records I have to put into salesforce. Salesforce only allows me to insert 200 records per iteration !
Unfortunately I have can not get all these records in one db call, it overloads the machine memory.
So my idea was to do use a "foreach" component in Mule to keep on looping until I get less then 200 records from my db call.

How can these been accomplished ?

My config flow is here:

```
<foreach batchSize="200" doc:name="For Each" counterVariableName="foreachCount">
        <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="select200records" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="postgresConnector" doc:name="Database">
            <jdbc-ee:query key="select200records" value="select * from parties limit 200 offset #[variable:offset]"/>
        </jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>
        <set-variable variableName="dbPayload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <scripting:component doc:name="Script">
            <scripting:script engine="jython"><![CDATA[result = len(payload)]]></scripting:script>
        </scripting:component>
....
```

Comment: Another way to phrase the question:
Does Mule have a "While loop" I have just seen the "foreach" component ?

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce has a variety of batch api limits

Batches for data loads can consist of a single CSV or XML file that can be no larger than 10 MB.

- A batch can contain a maximum of 10,000 records.
- A batch can contain a maximum of 10,000,000 characters for all the data in a batch.
- A field can contain a maximum of 32,000 characters.
- A record can contain a maximum of 5,000 fields.
- A record can contain a maximum of 400,000 characters for all its fields.
- A batch must contain some content or an error occurs.

If your using the mule salesforce connector there is a Bulk option that I recall allows more than the default batch size.

Comment: I get where your are going. The problem is my db adapter in Mule can not handle all these records in memory, that is my main concern how to fetch like 200 records from the db adapter in each iteration. Do you know how I could do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The Mule EE JDBC transport provides a BatchManager for exactly this use case.  See [Large Dataset Retrieval](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/JDBC+Transport+Reference#JDBCTransportReference-LargeDataset) in the user guide.